# Convert a String to a java.util.Stream<Character>

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

Sometimes I want to do something simple with each character in a string. Unfortunately, because a string is immutable, there is no good way of doing it except looping through the string which can be quite verbose. If you would use a Stream instead, it could be done much shorter, in just a line or two.

Is there a way to convert a `String` into a `Stream<Character>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `chars()` method provided in `CharSequence` and since `String` class implements this interface you can access it.
The `chars()` method returns an `IntStream` , so you need to cast it to `(char)` if you will like to convert `IntStream` to `Stream<Character>`

E.g.

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "new";

        Stream<Character> characters = x.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i);
        characters.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution does not work if the string contains Unicode character that does not fit in a Java char. This is the case, for example, with some arcane languages as well as emoticons. See [Tagir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32472793/452775) for a solutions that handles that.

Answer (score 9):

It's usually more safe to use stream of code points which is `IntStream`:

```
IntStream codePoints = string.codePoints();
```

This way Unicode surrogate pairs will be merged into single codepoint, so you will have correct results with any Unicode symbols. Example usage:

```
String result = string.codePoints().map(Character::toUpperCase)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
```

Also note that you avoid boxing, thus it might be even more effective than processing `Stream<Character>`.

Another way to collect such stream is to use separate `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String result = string.codePoints().map(Character::toUpperCase)
                      .forEachOrdered(sb::appendCodePoint);
```

While such approach looks less functional, it may be more efficient if you already have a `StringBuilder` or want to concatenate something more later to the same string.

Comment: Plus one for suggesting codePoints() in preference to chars().

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chars` method which returns `IntStream` and by mapping it to `char` you will have `Stream<Character>`. `mapToObj` returns `Object` valued `Stream` in our case `Stream` of `Character`, because we have mapped the `int` to `char` and java *Auto Boxed* it to `Character` *internally*.

```
Stream<Character> stream = "abc".chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c);
```

Moreover, with the help of guava (`com.google.common.collect.Lists`) you can use it like this, which return immutable list of `Character` from the `String`.

```
Stream<Character> stream = Lists.charactersOf("abc").stream();
```