# Create a Stream<Character> from a Stream<String>

Tags: java, string, char, java-stream

I try to convert a Stream of String into Stream of Char.
example:

```
Stream<String> -> "Hello", "World"

Stream<Char> -> "H","e","l","l","o","W","o","r","l","d"
```

I allready tried to go for 
`Stream<Character> temp = stream.forEachOrdered(s -> s.chars())` and maybe map them into a Char stream but I cant figure it out..

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471799/convert-a-string-to-a-java-util-streamcharacter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32471932/845414):

```
Stream<String> foo = ...
Stream<Character> characters = foo.flatMap(x -> x.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i));
```

or

```
Stream<Character> characters = foo.flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i);
```

Just use `flatMap` or `flatMapToInt`.

Answer (score -2):

In Java 9+, the String class has a new method chars()  that returns an IntStream.
From there you can use Character.valueOf.

In Java 8 it's more complex. You can get a char array with String.toCharArray, but then you have to convert your `char[]` to `Character[]` before using `Arrays.stream(T[])`.
However, as far as I know, there is no built-in way to convert from `char[]` to `Character[]` without using a library or coding your own conversion method.

Comment: [The String class has the `chars()` method since Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#methods.inherited.from.class.java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Sorry, no. See [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). It is written Since: 9 below the chars() method in question.

Comment: **Specified by:**
    [chars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars()) in interface [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) - The override of `chars` for `String` was added in Java 9, but CharSequence has a default method `chars()` since Java 8.